# cursor changes to pointer for only portion of an image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set cursor: pointer when hovering over an image.  My current code only seems to work for the top portion of the image but not the entire thing.

I've reproduced the issue with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thetoolsmith/53rqnyx6/)

My CSS class looks like this:

```
.profile-avatar-img {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Any idea why the cursor is only working for the top few pixels of the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `margin-top` seems to be causing the issue

Change

```
.profile-buttons {
margin-right: 15px;
margin-top: 110px;
}
```

to

```
.profile-buttons {
 margin-right: 15px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/53rqnyx6/2/

Comment: that does seem to be the issue...any idea why that's happening?

Comment: @Paul i don't exactly know but it is because of the buttons see this http://jsfiddle.net/xt48177f/ i gave `margin-top:100px' and gave it absolute position and then it seems to be working fine

Comment: Thanks, for some reason margin works but padding causes the issue.